# wysiwyg редактор с кастомными блоками для сайта

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg

Подскажите, есть ли wysiwyg редактор, в котором можно добавить свой блок с выбором параметров. Это должно работать так:

- перетаскиваем блок "Список новостей" в область редактирования
- в этой области щелкаем по блоку "Список новостей" и выбираем параметры: категория "Новости компании" (выпадающий список), количество новостей: 10
- при сохранении получается примерно такая разметка

```
<h1>Новости компании</h1>

<component>
  <type>news</type>
  <params>
    <category>17</category>
    <count>10</count>
  </params>
</component>
```

Эту разметку будет парсить PHP (это я смогу сделать сам) и в результате получится страница с заголовком и подгруженными новостями.

Нечто подобное есть в Битриксе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Сложно ответить однозначно, т.к. не понятно какую цель вы преследуете. Следует отталкиваться от конкретных требований.
Дело в том что wysiwyg не обладают функционалом "Список новостей". Из коробки их функционал не превышает минимум редактора Word.
В битриксе используется "**Setka Editor**" Но сам он с новостями не работает, это уже его целевая заточка под конкретное решение в виде битрикс.
Таким образом "**Параметры**" дорабатываются программистом отдельно на базе wysiwyg под конкретную **CMS**.
В пример для Wordpress'а есть **Unyson**, который позволяет работать с блочной сеткой 5 колонок. В нем есть базовый набор элементов для контента, вроде текстового блока, таблицы, видео или картинки. Но программист может доработать дополнительные элементы вроде "**списка новостей с переключателем 10|20|50**".
Основной Момент в том что сами Новости как таковые берутся из **CMS**, а wysiwyg это просто редактор текста который превращает текст в html-тэги.

Дополнительный функционал поддерживают почти все актуальные WYSIWYG. Например вот [тут](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/advanced/creating-a-custom-button/) для **tinymce** добавляется кнопочка которая вставляет текущую дату(а далее и параметрическую шестеренку). Если разобраться в коде можно создавать довольно мощный кастомный функционал.

Comment: Спасибо. Обновил вопрос, чтобы было понятнее. Я понимаю, что WYSIWYG это редактор для работы с HTML, но в Битриксе же сделали то что мне нужно. Но решение будет на другом фреймворке, поэтому не подходит. Посмотрел Setka Editor и Unyson, в них нет необходимого, или то что можно допилить. tinymce - при клике действительно формируется код, но нужно чтобы это не был HTML, а спецразметка для парсинга PHP, и визуально показывалось в виде блока. Этот функционал нужен для обывателей, которые не знают HTML, не понимают разметку. Им нужен "блок", щелкнул по нему, увеличил кол-во новостей, или уменьшил

Comment: Внутри редактора Битрикса это сохраняется шорткодами вида [news maxcount=10]
Вы можете реализовать это в TinyMCE, а уже на стороне PHP при выводе страницы на просмотр, искать и заменять все шорткоды по параметрам.

Comment: Нет, в битриксе работает по-другому, там вставляется PHP-код, который парсится редактором. Можете подсказать как сделать подобное в TinyMCE через шорт коды или подобное?

Comment: Можно PHP. Смотрите документацию и ссылку которую я скинул. Там на примере вставки времени смотрите функцию toTimeHtml(date) она возвращает HTML-строку. Меняете эту хтмл строку на формат который вам нужен. хоть пхп хоть шорткод. Изучите разработку плагинов для tinymce.

Comment: Боюсь, это не совсем то. `она возвращает HTML-строку` а мне нужно чтобы в исходном коде показывался шорткод, но в редакторе был такой "кирпичик", по которому можно щелкнуть и настроить в диалоговом окне параметры. Конечный пользователь не должен видеть шорт кодов. Я посмотрел по ссылке. Или все-таки можно так сделать?

Comment: А как по вашему он с картинками работает? вы загружаете картинку а он преобразует её в хтмл. В редакторе всегда будет картинка, а в содержании хтмл-тэг img

Comment: Это логично. Но я боюсь, что в tinymce так работает только с картинками. Если вы уверены что так можно, напишите. Или еще лучше дайте ссылку где это реализовано. Конечно, можно копаться в сорцах, изучать как это работает. Но это черезчур сложно для меня.